How to setup swagger with SwaggerDocument to pass through Bearer Token to the endpoints
I am using Fastendpoint and trying to setup swagger with authorization header, I have the following setup
builder.Services.AddFastendpoints().SwaggerDocument();
it does not seem to pass the bearer token to the services.
I have used the following configuration
builder.Services.AddSwaggerDocument( config.PostProcess = document =>
        {

            document.Info.Contact = new NSwag.OpenApiContact
            {
                Name = "Name of the application",                
            };
        };

        config.AddSecurity("Bearer", Enumerable.Empty<string>(), new NSwag.OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Type = NSwag.OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            Name = "Authorization",
            In = NSwag.OpenApiSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header,
            Description = "Enter 'Bearer' followed by a space and your token.",
        });

but documentation does not suggest it. what is the right way to do that with builder.Services.SwaggerDocument()

.SwaggerDocument() already includes jwt bearer auth. if you want to do it yourself, have a look at this sample from the docs.

Thanks DJ I was looking for Bearer token and it is in the sample

Thanks to 
Dĵ ΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ Fastendpoints has got a preconfigured swagger document for JWTBearAuth authentication but if you need to use Bear token you need to follow the sample code at sample
